# Passing the results of `std::string::c_str()` to `mkdtemp()` using `const_cast<char*>()`

Tags: c++, stdstring, mutable, c-strings, const-cast

OK, so: we all know that generally the use of `const_cast<>()` anywhere is so bad it’s practically a programming war crime. So this is a hypothetical question about *how bad* it might be, exactly, in a specific case.

To wit: I ran across some code that did something like this:

```
std::string temporary = "/tmp/directory-XXXXX";
const char* dtemp = ::mkdtemp(const_cast<char*>(temporary.c_str()));
/// `temporary` is unused hereafter
```

… now, I have run across numerous descriptions about how to get writeable access to the underlying buffer of a `std::string` instance (q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15863513/298171 for example) – all of them have the caveat that yes, these methods aren’t guaranteed to work by any C++ standard, but in practice they all do.

With this in mind, I am just curious on how using `const_cast<char*>(string.c_str())` compares to other known methods (e.g. the aforementioned `&string[0]`, &c)… I ask because the code in which I found this method in use seems to work fine in practice, and I thought I’d see what the experts thought before I attempt the inevitable `const_cast<>()`-free rewrite.

Comment: Use `std::vector<char>` instead of `std::string`.  You have the writable buffer without all of the casting.

Comment: Not what I am asking – I can think of a bunch of ways to do it that don’t have the problem. I am curious about the nature of what makes the problem problematic.

Comment: Btw: A correct implementation would be this: `char temporary[] = "/tmp/directory-XXXXX"; char* dtemp = mkdtemp(temporary);` Since this creates an array on the stack, which is initialized with a copy of the string literal, you have all right to modify that copy, including passing it to `mkdtemp()`. True, no shiny C++ stuff used here, but it's shorter, simpler, and more correct than the version you ran across :-)

Comment: @cmaster absolutely yes – while that would be saner _and_ less circuitous, the snippet I posted is a serious oversimplification of the actual production code, which naturally is messy enough to make such a straightforward edit unstraightforwardly doable. But you are certainly correct about doing a static assignment to a writeable stack-based temporary as ideal fodder for `mkdtemp()` usage, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `const` cannot be enforced at hardware level because in practice, in non-hypothetical environment, you can set read-only attribute only to a full 4K memory page and there are huge pages on the way, which drastically reduce CPU's lookup misses in the [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_Lookaside_Buffer).
- `const` doesn't affect code generation like `__restrict` from C99 does. In fact, `const`, roughly speaking, means "poison all write attempts to this data, I'd like to protect my invariants here"

Since `std::string` is a mutable string, its underlying buffer cannot be allocated in read-only memory. So `const_cast<>` shouldn't cause program crash here unless you're going to change some bytes outside of underlying buffer's bounds or trying to `delete`, `free()` or `realloc()` something. However, altering of chars in the buffer may be classified as invariant violation. Because you don't use `std::string` instance after that and simply throw it away this shouldn't provoke program crash unless some particular `std::string` implementation decide to check its invariants' integrity before destruction and force a crash if some of these are broken. Because such check couldn't be done in less than O(N) time and `std::string` is a performance critical class, it is unlikely to be done by anyone.

Another issue may come from [Copy-on-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) strategy. So, by modifying the buffer directly you may break some other `std::string`'s instance which shares the buffer with your string. But few years ago majority of C++ experts came to conclusion that COW is too fragile and too slow especially in multi-threaded environments, so modern C++ libraries shouldn't use it and instead adhere to using move construction where possible and avoiding heap traffic for small length strings where applicable.

Comment: Huh wow yeah – that does explain why it works in this case (passing it to `mkdtemp()` which replaces characters but doesn’t reallocate anything, as far as I know).

Comment: …or changing a character to `'\0'`.

Comment: Well, I think this is a bit misleading. It's not permitted to cast away the `const` *and then write to the buffer through that pointer*. You can only read.   To get write access to the string contents, use `&s[0]`.

Comment: @M.M Right, that was my assumption – but like I said, it seems to work OK in that snippet, so is that a compiler fluke (I am using the latest `clang++` FYI) or something else I am not aware of that is allowing both compilation and execution to go ahead here?

Comment: @fish2000 it causes undefined behaviour, which may include appearing to work as intended. Or to put it another way, compilers may or may not support it (and you don't get any warning if they don't)

Comment: @M.M Ahaaaa yes the dreaded UB – thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: a) `const` cannot be enforced at hardware level
b) `const` doesn't affect code generation like `__restrict` from C99. 

In fact, `const`, roughly speaking, means "poison all write attempts to this stuff, this hopefully protects my invariants".

Comment: @MinorThreat … so does that mean that `const` is, at root, a compiler directive and nothing else?

Comment: @MinorThreat Nice! I truly appreciate COW-related details. Would upvote again if I could, thanks Dr. Threat.

Comment: N.B. What @MinorThreat is talking about w/r/t shared buffers will be more relevant once we get `std::experimental::string_view` finalized – q.v. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view

Comment: About checking invariants in the destructor: `std::string::size()` is defined to be of `O(1)` complexity, so all implementations need to keep either the size or a pointer to the end of the string around. That information is enough to do a sanity check of the null-byte at the end of the string in constant time. So an implementation *could* force a crash if the terminating byte is overwritten.

Comment: @cmaster I do believe @MinorThreat was talking hypothetically about a putative `std::string` implementation crashing on destruction, should its invariant internals appear altered in some detectable fashion – however our respective actual `std::string` internals work, they benefit no one if they can’t be destructed in a way that is a) unflinchingly parsimoniously performant, and b) guaranteed `noexcept` … two qualities essential for `std::string` to be ubiquitously, generally, usefully safe across the board. Checking the trailing `NUL` doesn’t check integrity and makes the destructor dangerous.

Comment: @fish2000 I see it this way: The trailing `NUL` byte is put there implicitly by the implementation, and cannot be removed by legal user code. Hence, if the `NUL` byte is overwritten, the program has *already* entered UB. Aborting the process is a perfectly permissible course of action in such a case, and the check is cheap. True, that's pretty much of a language-lawyer point of view, but I've come to the conclusion that it's better to listen to the language-lawyers when it comes to UB. There are too many cases where code that used to work well broke miserably because a compiler proved UB.

Comment: In general you should strive to write code that "works by design", not "works by accident".  Casting away `const` here or going into undefined behavior land puts you squarely in the "works by accident" mode.  Later, the compiler is updated and changes the response to undefined behavior (they can do that) and you recompile your code and suddenly it is crashing somewhere weird on occasion.  Just avoid undefined behavior and make your code "work by design" instead of by accident.

Comment: @legalize: Of course we're supposed to do everything possible to avoid UB. But @fish2000 asked what exactly could happen. `const` doesn't say that the data can't be altered at all. It say that you're not supplied with a proper interface to alter these data in this particular scope. But there are different scopes and compiler can't track them all, in general.

Comment: @MinorThreat Because we're entering the realm of undefined behavior, the answer of what *could* happen is literally anything the compiler feels like doing, including [invoking `hack`, or the towers of hanoi game](http://feross.org/gcc-ownage/).

Comment: @legalize: I saw some cases when Microsoft did rely on UB. ATL/WTL thunk code on the stack, type conversions via `union`s, `void(*)(LPRECT)` -> void(*)(const CRect&), etc etc.